# Install my own SQL Server 2008 copy on Amazon

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2008, amazon-ec2

Can I install SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition that I got though BizSpark on Amazon EC2?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to install MS-SQL on a Windows Server instance and generate an AMI of the server image, but since EC2 instances do not maintain local storage between instance restarts you'll need to do some serious thinking about how you are going to persist your database storage across instance restarts.

Amazon also offers pre-build AMIs with SQL Server installed and configured to use their EBS service which will persist data across instance restarts.  You may be better off using one of their existing AMIs for this instead of rolling your own.

Comment: Definitely better to use the Amazon-provided AMI.  That BizSpark copy of SQL Server 2008 need not go to waste, as it would be great for a local development/test environment.

Comment: thanks. We are already using SQL Server 2005 Express on Amazon. Our app is a 24x7 app, so there won't be a "restart" scenario. The reason I asked the question is because, since our DB will be growing beyond 4GB, soon we will need to upgrade to SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition. I was just wondering about the licensing issues with using BizSpark license on Amazon EC2. 

One problem with Amazon AMI having SQL Server pre-installed is that we will have to pay extra money for that. Since I have a BizSpark license that I can use in production, I would rather use it instead of Amazon AMI.

Comment: Ah, well your question didn't mention anything about whether the license could be used there.  That would have been a good point to mention. :)  I'm not sure of an answer to that, but my gut tells me that it would be fine when installed on a standard Windows server there.  We're talking about Microsoft though, so I wouldn't rely on my gut when it comes to their licensing terms.